# How to save and show on DetailView data associated with another data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'd really appreciate any help. I have the following code:

views.py:

```
class Booklist(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/books.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CreatePost.PostForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form  = CreatePost.PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form })

class CreatePost(CreateView):
    template_name_suffix='_create'

    class PostForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = ['post']  
            widgets = {
            'post': forms.Textarea()
            }

class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context

...
```

How can I save and show post data associated with each book? Right now the program shows the book list. And after saving post through the form that's on each book item (weird design) and clicking on the book item, it shows the post list (so on the DetailView of the book item).

But no matter which book item is clicked, all the posts are showing. And the posts are saved only in association with the first book no matter to which book item you save the post.

I would like to save the post and have it be associated with the specific book on whom is the form that's used to save the post. And I'd like to show (on DetailView of the book) only the posts associated with that book.

I think I need to have the form pass book data as well... But everything I've tried hasn't worked (adding model=Book, etc.). Perhaps by adding to form Meta the same code from update (please see the bottom of the page)?

More code:

models.py:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False, default="1")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False)
    the_book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="1")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post
```

books.html:

```
<ul>
    {% for book in object_list %}
    <div class='ui card'>
    <a class="content" href='{% url 'books:posts' book.id %}'>
      <div class="header">{{ book }}</div>
    </a>

    <div class="ui bottom attached button">

       <form class='ui form' action='' method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }} 
          <div class='postbutton'>
          <input class='ui button' type="submit" value="Done" />
          </div>
      </form>

    </div>

    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <h5>You don't have any books!</h5>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

post_create.html (the name will be changed later...):

```
 <ul>
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class='ui card'>
    <a class="content">
      <div class="header">{{ post }}</div>
    </a>
    </div>
    {% empty %}
    <h5>You don't have any posts!</h5>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Also how can I show date model on DetailView, the post_create.html (and other data in the Post model)?

Please excuse things that might annoy due to their newbieness...

Again, any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:**

On showing post list (on DetailView of book) that's associated with each specific book item:

After changing models.py to:

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        books = Book.objects.get(pk=book)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(the_book=books)
        context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

Clicking on a book shows, instead of post list, "name 'book' is not defined". Same when just (book) or (pk=book_id) or (pk=book.id).

And after this:

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=book)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(the_book=book)
        context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

It shows: "local variable 'book' referenced before assignment."

And after this:

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        book = Book.objects.get(pk=id)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(the_book=book)
        context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

It shows: "int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'"

What should I do? Also please see my other questions in the middle of the post. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I can't understand your question well. What exactly you want to do? Can you describe more?

Comment: If you don't want all of the posts returned, you probably shouldn't use `Post.objects.all()`..

Comment: @seuling I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh if you use `DetailView`, you can use `self.object`. It's defined in `DetailView`.

If you look at `DetailView` code (you can see django github or [here](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/)), you can find `get()` and `get_object()`.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

As you see, when you request by get in `DetailView`, `self.object` is defined using `self.get_object()`.

Here's `get_object()` method from `DetailView`.(Actually, it's from `SingleObjectMixin` and `DetailView` inherit it.

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    """
    Return the object the view is displaying.
    Require `self.queryset` and a `pk` or `slug` argument in the URLconf.
    Subclasses can override this to return any object.
    """
    # Use a custom queryset if provided; this is required for subclasses
    # like DateDetailView
    if queryset is None:
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
    # Next, try looking up by primary key.
    pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg)
    slug = self.kwargs.get(self.slug_url_kwarg)
    if pk is not None:
        queryset = queryset.filter(pk=pk)
    # Next, try looking up by slug.
    if slug is not None and (pk is None or self.query_pk_and_slug):
        slug_field = self.get_slug_field()
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{slug_field: slug})
    # If none of those are defined, it's an error.
    if pk is None and slug is None:
        raise AttributeError("Generic detail view %s must be called with "
                             "either an object pk or a slug."
                             % self.__class__.__name__)
    try:
        # Get the single item from the filtered queryset
        obj = queryset.get()
    except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404(_("No %(verbose_name)s found matching the query") %
                      {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})
    return obj
```

So, you can use `self.object`. like below

```
class Posts(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name='books/post_create.html'
    slug_field = 'id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        book = self.object
        posts = Post.objects.filter(the_book=book)
        context['posts'] = posts
        return context
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I've posted a new question for the other part that I couldn't figure out. If you get a chance, I'd appreciate your help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937098/associating-a-model-with-another-model-when-saving-it

Answer (score 0):

Your application shows all of the posts because you are using `Post.objects.all()`. This will return all of the `Post` objects in your database. Instead, use the book you're currently viewing to filter them.

I can't understand from your code how you obtain what book you're viewing, but if you have the `book` id, you could do:

```
book = Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)
posts = Post.objects.filter(the_book=book)
```

This way, `posts` will contain all of the `Post` objects that are attached to the book.

The reason all of your posts are assigned to the first book, is because you are not passing the book anywhere in your form. So it defaults to the value you have defined in your model: `1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have updated the question.